# Background Image for Select (dropdown) does not work in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I want to use an image for the background of a select/dropdown. The following CSS works fine in Firefox and IE, but does not in Chrome:

```
#main .drop-down-loc { width:506px; height: 30px; border: none; 
  background-color: Transparent; 
  background: url(images/text-field.gif) no-repeat 0 0; 
  padding:4px; line-height: 21px;}
```

Answer (score 80):

```
select 
{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

If you need to you can also add an image that contains the arrow as part of the background.

Comment: btw - this will remove your down arrow graphic on select too.

Comment: since there will a background, that can clearly be part of the background image.

Comment: I always prefer solution over preaching! +1

Comment: Is there a way to do it in Firefox as well ? I meam make the down arrow to disappear ...

Comment: Partially solves the issue of the background-image, but introduces usability/form-control consistency issues, and forces you to consider the select arrow as part of your background image. Not ideal, but might be good in certain cases.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the chrome issue. I had the arrow image to my background image.

Answer (score 6):

What Arne said - you can't reliably style select boxes and have them look anything like consistent across browsers.

Uniform: https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform is a javascript solution which gives you good graphic control over your form elements - it's still Javascript, but it's about as nice as javascript gets for solving this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, it's considered a bad practice to style standard form controls because the output looks so different on each browser. See: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-single/ for some rendered examples.

That being said, I've had some luck making the background color an RGBA value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background: #d00;
      }
      select {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1) url('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo6g.png') repeat-x 0 0; 
        padding:4px; 
        line-height: 21px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select>
      <option>Foo</option>
      <option>Bar</option>      
      <option>Something longer</option>     
  </body>
</html>
```

Google Chrome still renders a gradient on top of the background image in the color that you pass to rgba(r,g,b,0.1) but choosing a color that compliments your image and making the alpha 0.1 reduces the effect of this.

Comment: Adding line height to class applied to select element solves the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS styles below for all browsers except Firefox 30:

```
select {
  background: url(dropdown_arw.png) no-repeat right center;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 90px;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: "";
}
```

**Updated**

Here is a solution for Firefox 30. There is a little trick for custom select elements in firefox :-moz-any() CSS pseudo class.

Comment: Does not work in IE and in MS Edge it is showing text on top of the background