# Magento how to display country flag in currency drop down?

Tags: php, magento, themes, magento-1.4

I am trying to add all country flag in currency change dropdown in magento?

how may i do this in magento 1.4.2 ?

Comment: Images in select controls are [problematic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2226666/471559). This is not a Magento limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Very good example for flags. It may help others
http://www.phptechi.com/magento-show-country-flags-selector-in-header.html

As stated in that post:

> Step 1: Make sure multiple language stores are available. Now open
>   flags.phhml file located at
>   app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/switch/flags.html If
>   in case it does not exists then create it and replace existing code/
>   add following code into file.
>
> Note: Please modify href & src in following code.
>
> ```
> < ?php if(count($this->getGroups())>1): ?>
>
> < ?php foreach ($this->getGroups() as $_group): ?>
> < ?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_group->getName()) ?>
> < ?php endforeach; ?> 
> < ?php endif; ?>
> ```
>
> Step 2: Now add entry into page.xml file and file header block i.e.
>   “html_header”. In case if you want to add flags in footer section then
>   search for footer block and add following line in footer and do little
>   css to align it correctly.
>
> Step 3: Upload flag images into “skin/frontend/currentTheme/images/”
>   directory and make sure the flag file names are having store name is
>   part of flag name. (i.e. Image name is “flagEnglish.gif”,
>   “flagGerman.gif”. So store names are “English”, “German”, etc)
>
> Now clean the magento cache and reload the home page and you are
>   done!!.

Answer (score 0):

Currency selector with flag in magento

1. You need to prepare a flag list (images).
2. Upload flag list to root/media/flag directory
3. Rename flags to currency’s code (EX: US Dollar -> usd-flag.jpg, Euro -> eur-flag.jpg, Hong Kong Dollar -> hkd-flag.jpg...)
4. In the template file: app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/directory/currency.phtml (or app/design/frontend/base/default/template/directory/currency.phtml), change code to:

   ```
   <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>" onclick="setLocation(this.value);">
           <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'flag/'.$_code.'.jpg'; ?>" title="<?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>" alt="<?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>" width="20" height="20" />
           </a>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   ```