# Style disabled multiple select – google chrome

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, multiple-select

I’m trying to figure out how I can go about styling a disabled multiple select element, for google chrome so you can see the selected items.

I’ve seem to have it working in:

**Mac:** firefox, safari and chrome
**PC:** ie7, ie8, and firefox

It’s just the windows version of chrome that’s not working (see image).

[image: google chrome issue]

How can a go about change the foreground color, or the disabled selected color so you can read the selected text?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like this is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=97374) with no work-around.

Comment: I just add a `style="color:white"` attribute

Answer (score 4):

I don't entirely understand your goal, but I ran into a similar problem in Chrome on Windows trying to style a select element (not disabled). The element was given a white background by the browser and I could not override it, until I tried this:

```
{ -webkit-appearance: none; }
```

And it worked! I hope this helps.

Source: [Background Image for Select (dropdown) does not work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226666/background-image-for-select-dropdown-does-not-work-in-chrome)

Comment: Somehow if you test through chrom firebug it won't affect, but changing the CSS with that it does work.