# Styling disabled <select> in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

For styling disabled elements I used:

```
[disabled] { /* Text and background colour, medium red on light yellow */
color:#933;
background-color:#ffc;
}
```

It's work perfectly in all browsers except Chrome. Is there exists a way to overcome this using css without classes, because I have a huge amount of  elements on different pages and don't want to change it all.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

After some investigation I have realized that this can be reproduced only if client has a  server OS like Windows 2008 and use only Chrome browser. But I hope its a rear condition in real life.

Comment: Have you tried using `[disabled="disabled"]`?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't work too.

Comment: Have you tried styling the disabled element with inline-styles or through a custom CSS class to make sure its even possible to style the disabled element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be working just fine using Chrome 15.

```
input[disabled] {
  color: #933;
  background-color: #ffc;
}
```

Make sure you´ve cleared any cached style sheets.

Created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayYpN/1).

**UPDATE**

Noticed your question title and updated the example.

It´s seems to be a known issue for Chrome in Windows, see [Style disabled multiple select – google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692442/style-disabled-multiple-select-google-chrome)

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly, but it depended on the server OS. On my local Windows 7 it works, but on the server Windows 2008 it doesn't work.

Comment: For me it works with Windows 7 but not with Windows XP. Did I answer your question? :)

Comment: Yes, I think your answer is the most close to the solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is works for me (style the option colors not select box itself):

```
<select multiple="multiple" disabled="disabled">
<option style="color:#CCCCCC;" value="1" selected>Monday</option>
<option style="color:#CCCCCC;" value="2" selected>Tuesday</option>
<option style="color:#CCCCCC;" value="3">Wednesday</option>
<option style="color:#CCCCCC;" value="4">Thursday</option>
<option style="color:#CCCCCC;" value="5">Friday</option>
<option style="color:#CCCCCC;" value="6">Saturday</option>
<option style="color:#CCCCCC;" value="7">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Orhun Alp Oral, but it seems not to be a problem for modern versions of Chrome at all.

Comment: This does not seem to work in IE, but I can set the background color in IE, which also solved my problem.