# select box background image

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Background Image for Select (dropdown) does not work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226666/background-image-for-select-dropdown-does-not-work-in-chrome)

I need to change the select box background image to https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo101.png
I am using this code:

```
<form>
    <select id='selectbox'>
        <option >A</option>
        <option >B</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

it might sound trivial but I tried all sorts of things and unfortunately they all failed.Any help would be appreciated

FIXED: I used this to fix it:

```
select#selectbox { -webkit-appearance: none; }
```

Comment: What have you tried? And do you get any errors? Also, why are you trying to use a Google Sprite Sheet?

Comment: Works fine for me: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JJuP5/).

Comment: ohh. doesn't work in chrome. I tested it in firefox it works. any ideas about chrome?

Comment: the google logo is just for a demo. I have an other image on my hd

Comment: Based on comments, dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2226666/422184

Answer (score 4):

Look here http://jsfiddle.net/8FydL/

```
form select#selectbox {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo101.png');
}
```

Comment: thanks Mattia, that's what I tried,it doesn't work on chrome... any ideas?

Comment: I use chrome and it works for me... Can i see all the css code? i can help you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8FydL/ this same page if I open it in chrome it doesn't show the image

Comment: No idea... I use chrome and http://jsfiddle.net/8FydL works for me :( Try this code: 
`background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo101.png);`

Comment: the key for me was defining the height