# Background image x px from right edge

Tags: css

I have `<select>` elements of various widths on a site. I want to position a background image `13px` from the right-edge of the select width. In pseudo-code:

```
select {
    background-image: url(../images/select-arrow.png), 
    background-position: center (right - 13px);
}
```

How would I do this in CSS?

Comment: Not possible. You'll have to give the PNG some transparent padding, or update the position in real time using Javascript

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226666/background-image-for-select-dropdown-does-not-work-in-chrome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[CSS3 redefines the background-property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position) so that you can say:

```
background-position: right 13px top;
```

<strike>However browsersupport isn't the best atm.</strike>

To work around this, you can:

- add transparent pixels to the image itself and positioning it top right
- or calculate the position with javascript after the element's width is known

EDIT: [You can safely use this feature now.](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-position)