# How to add background-image to select-box?

Tags: html, css

I have done what is answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226666/background-image-for-select-dropdown-does-not-work-in-chrome) but I haven't had luck so far in Google Chrome.

The code below works just fine in Firefox though:

```
select {
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: ""; 
}

option {
    background: transparent        url(http://www.clinicalflow.com/skins/common/icons/ed_ins_img.png)     no-repeat left center;
    padding-left: 20px;  
    width: 200px;
}
```

Any hints?

[Here is the fiddle I have been playing with](http://jsfiddle.net/pm86r8bm/2/).

Comment: You can use http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ or http://websemantics.github.io/Image-Select/

Answer (score 2):

Should be like this:

```
option {
    background: transparent url(http://www.clinicalflow.com/skins/common/icons/ed_ins_img.png) no-repeat left center;
    padding-left: 20px;  
    width: 200px;
}
```

You were using semicolon just after the `background: transparent;` and after that url which is wrong.

Comment: Heh, you beat me to it by a second

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo I made when pasting the code in SO. If you check out the fiddle it is just the way you wrote it.

Comment: There in the fiddle also, you are using `;` after transparent.

Comment: Sorry again. That was a edit in the fiddle. Will check out everything in the future before asking again in SO. If you try the current linked edition is just the way you wrote it in the first place.

Comment: Oh! I checked your updated fiddle and tried to set in select which is working fine but not with option, I think not possible, or need some re-search... http://jsfiddle.net/pm86r8bm/4/

Comment: Look here, we can't do simply but can do with bootstrap, please research there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/cssselect-dropdown-option

Comment: Thanks for following up! Will keep the question open and see if there is another option for this, though.

Comment: You should at least believe by seeing the most upvoted question answer.... that there no other way around...

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for all browsers [jsfiddle.net/8FydL/445](http://jsfiddle.net/8FydL/445/)

about options  with `background-image.`

This is a known solution and helps me many many times.
The solution came from [here:](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/reinventing-a-drop-down-with-css-and-jquery/)

CSS:

```
.desc { color:#6b6b6b;}
.desc a {color:#0092dd;}

.dropdown dd, .dropdown dt, .dropdown ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
.dropdown dd { position:relative; }
.dropdown a, .dropdown a:visited { color:#816c5b; text-decoration:none; outline:none;}
.dropdown a:hover { color:#5d4617;}
.dropdown dt a:hover { color:#5d4617; border: 1px solid #d0c9af;}
.dropdown dt a {background:#e4dfcb url('http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/reinventing-drop-down/arrow.png') no-repeat scroll right center; display:block; padding-right:20px;
                border:1px solid #d4ca9a; width:150px;}
.dropdown dt a span {cursor:pointer; display:block; padding:5px;}
.dropdown dd ul { background:#e4dfcb none repeat scroll 0 0; border:1px solid #d4ca9a; color:#C5C0B0; display:none;
                  left:0px; padding:5px 0px; position:absolute; top:2px; width:auto; min-width:170px; list-style:none;}
.dropdown span.value { display:none;}
.dropdown dd ul li a { padding:5px; display:block;}
.dropdown dd ul li a:hover { background-color:#d0c9af;}

.dropdown img.flag { border:none; vertical-align:middle; margin-left:10px; }
.flagvisibility { display:none;}
```

JS:

```
 $(".dropdown img.flag").addClass("flagvisibility");
    $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
        $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
    });

    $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
        var text = $(this).html();
        $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
        $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
        $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
    });

    function getSelectedValue(id) {
        return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
    }

    $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
            $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
    });

    $(".dropdown img.flag").toggleClass("flagvisibility");
```

and Demo Html:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
        <dt><a href="#"><span>Please select the country</span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Brazil<img class="flag" src="http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/reinventing-drop-down/br.png" alt="" /><span class="value">BR</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">France<img class="flag" src="http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/reinventing-drop-down/fr.png" alt="" /><span class="value">FR</span></a></li>

            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <span id="result"></span>
```

Hope, that will save your day :) !