# Why Image drop downlist does not show images on some browsers?

Tags: html, css

I want to show some images on a dropdownlist to be selected by the users. I used the below Html code but it just shows the images on the Firefox browser. How may I make it possible to show the images on all browsers?

Html:

```
<select name="some_Images" id="some_Images">
  <option style="padding-left:0px;" value="">Select an Image</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(emotic/1.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat;" value="1">Image1</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(emotic/2.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat;" value="2">Image2</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(emotic/3.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat;" value="3">Image3</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(emotic/4.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat;" value="4">Image4</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(emotic/5.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat;" value="5">Image5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you checked it in other browser? On which browser this is not working?

Comment: As I said, the image are just available on Firefox.

Comment: Any errormessages in the other browsers?

Comment: check console and see what is actual error in other browser

Comment: There is not any Error.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you meet the same problem in below links?

[Background Image for Select (dropdown) does not work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226666/background-image-for-select-dropdown-does-not-work-in-chrome)

[select dropdown background-image not showing in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743222/select-dropdown-background-image-not-showing-in-chrome)