# Alternative for Option tag in HTML that can support images

Tags: html

Since images cannot be added to option tag, can someone please suggest an alternative for this, so that I can add image as well along with text. I am new to HTML, so I am not quite aware of all the tags.

Comment: Use radio buttons and add the images in the labels associated with the radio button - unless you want to allow multiple selection, then you'll need to use checkboxes.

Comment: Here you have the code to add image in option tag [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Comment: you have here some samples:
[samples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list) [sample 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508029/dropdown-select-with-images)

Answer (score 1):

You always have the option to use like this:

```
<select>
  <option style="background-image:url(image1.jpg);">male</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(image2.jpg);">female</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(image3.jpg);">others</option>
</select>
```

---

However, you can also use  [ddslick](http://designwithpc.com/plugins/ddslick)

> A free light weight jQuery plugin that allows you to create a custom drop down with images and description.

Comment: background-image works only in Firefox and is not supported in other browsers. Anyways, thanks for the answer...!!!

Comment: You can use simple un-ordered list to show dropdown and embedding images in that **[as mentioned in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FydL/445/)**. Source : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25743936/2815219